# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;) :Sparkcassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have been using `Spark 1.6` and `Cassandra connector 1.4.3` to write data to cassandra from spark.

Now, we upgraded to `Spark 2.1.0` and I tried to upgrade the `cassandra connector to 2.0.0-M3`, but it is returning the error as below:-

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.JavaApiHelper$.mirror(JavaApiHelper.scala:25)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.JavaApiHelper$.getTypeTag(JavaApiHelper.scala:29)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.JavaApiHelper.getTypeTag(JavaApiHelper.scala)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.typeTag(CassandraJavaUtil.java:159)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(CassandraJavaUtil.java:1172)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(CassandraJavaUtil.java:1205)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(CassandraJavaUtil.java:1222)
>           at com.cisco.cmcdp.EBdoUtils.upsertToJobAuditTable(EBdoUtils.java:370)
>           at com.cisco.cmcdp.EBdoContactPublisher.main(EBdoContactPublisher.java:245)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:637)

Pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Spark and Spark SQL, Hive Dependencies -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-mapr-1703</version>
                    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-mapr-1703</version>
                    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-mapr-1703</version>
                    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-mapr-1703</version>
                    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!--Spark Cassandra Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
                <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-clientutil</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
                <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Please suggest the appropriate way and version of Cassandra connector.

Regards,
Rishabh

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mostly due to usage of inappropriate Scala version, you might have mix of Scala 2.10 and Scala 2.11 libraries in your classpath. Ensure that you are using Spark 2.x, Spark Cassandra Connector 2.x and Scala 2.11 (Though Scala 2.10 is supported, but its better to use Scala 2.11). Take a look at following working maven configuration -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful, however I was able to resolve the issue by using 2.11 version of cassandra connector, I was using 2.10 earlier. below lib worked for me: spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.1.jar and spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11-1.6.0-M1.jar